# Satellite relative motion prediction using simulated data as a training data. I have a problem where I might have too much training data available

Tags: time-series

I am trying to model the satellite relative motion using regression. What I am doing is predicting the satellite relative motion using the Xu-Wang equations, which are a set of 11 first-order differential equations. So my training data would look as follows:

5 first-order differential equations, which define the chief orbit need to be propagated using some numerical integration technique, but the amount of possible perturbations these 5 variables can take is infinite for example:

a  = 6700 ~ 50000 km e = 0~0.99 i = 0~180 M =0~360 m = 0~360

and then for each above mentioned condition the secondary 6 variables can take infinitely many positions
x, y, z, = -1000km~1000km vx, vy, vz = -10km/sm~+10km/s.

and then each of these scenarios needs to be propagated into the future, and the future itself can be up to 15 years. so even if I take 1 reading every 1 hour or 1 day, the amount of data is too much. i.e. each initial data will generate a whole time series.

So really I am facing a problem where I may have too many possible situations to choose from. Is there a statistical tool or model that I can use to pick and choose which initial orbital conditions I should choose?

Comment: You would need to more information about those perturbations. What is the probabilistic model for perturbations? Are all perturbations normally distributed random variables? Are there correlations between them? If you have some prior data you can try to extract these using Bayesian statistics, but I am not sure there there is a ready tool for it. There are libraries such as PyMC3, Stan, [tensorflow_probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Bayesian_Switchpoint_Analysis), but it is not turn-key.

Comment: Once you know the corresponding probability distributions, you could simply sample from them to arrive at a set of representative future behaviours